# How to display NSWindow within the main window in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, swift, nswindow, makekeyandordertofront

I want to show a new window when an user taps on a button in the main window, but when I called the separate window using `makeKeyAndOrderFront`, the window popped up far away from the main window.

Here's what I wrote, in a subclass of `NSViewController`:

```
myWindow = NSWindow()
myWindow.setFrame(myView.frame, display: true)
myWindow.contentView = myView
myWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
```

However, this opens a new window outside of the main window. I want to display it within the main window, possibly in the center of the main window (I set the `.frame` value of `myView` to be positioned on the center).

So how can I call the new window within the main window? In other words, can I specify where the new window shows up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to convert the coordinates and or rect to screen space. 
NSView and NSWindow provide methods that begin with "convert" take a look at those. 
Sometimes you'll need to chain to convert from view space to window then window to screen. 
Keep in mind that a window has an NSScreen screen method and that a window could appear on many different size screens and potentially span multiple screens.

Comment: Oh, I just got that the seemingly scattered window is set from the bottom-left of the *screen*, not of the *main window*... Thanks.

Comment: Well Mac OS uses bottom left by default. NSWindow does have a lot of convenient methods for setting positions.